# HTML 3 Layers of PNG's

Tags: html, image, magento, html-table

Is it possible to have 3 layers of pngs on a table?
I am trying to do that:
[image]

This is a table with 6 columns.

- Grey Arrow - Table Backgorund Image
- Red Arrow - PNG in table
- Blue Arrow - Top Products Banner hovering

I did this rendering in photoshop, I'm curious if this is possible I have a setup that will work with the blue and grey but getting that bar that says Top Products on top seems to be a challenge. Note this is being done in a Magento CMS Page

Edit: here is my code so far

```
<table width="900" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td width="150" height="120" background="http://the-garage.net/homefiles/background/section1.jpg"><img src="http://www.the-garage.net/homefiles/testproduct.png" height="130" /></td>
<td  width="150" height="120" background="http://the-garage.net/homefiles/background/section2.jpg"><img src="http://www.the-garage.net/homefiles/testproduct.png" height="130" /></td>
<td width="150" height="120" background="http://the-garage.net/homefiles/background/section3.jpg"><img src="http://www.the-garage.net/homefiles/testproduct.png" height="130" /></td>
<td  width="150" height="120" background="http://the-garage.net/homefiles/background/section4.jpg"><img src="http://www.the-garage.net/homefiles/testproduct.png" height="130" /></td>
<td  width="150" height="120" background="http://the-garage.net/homefiles/background/section5.jpg"><img src="http://www.the-garage.net/homefiles/testproduct.png" height="130" /></td>
<td  width="150" height="120" background="http://the-garage.net/homefiles/background/section6.jpg"><img src="http://www.the-garage.net/homefiles/testproduct.png" height="130" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Description</td>
<td> Description</td>
<td> Description</td>
<td> Description</td>
<td> Description</td>
<td> Description</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: I guess you could put that table in a wrapper, make the wrapper position relative. Then add the top products banner and position it absolute.

Comment: Ill give that a try, any reason i got a downvote on this?

Comment: Oh yeah, be sure you either give the banner a high z-index or put it at the end of the wrapper, not the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put that table in a wrapper, make the wrapper position relative. Then add the top products banner and position it absolute. Be sure and give the banner a high z-index or put it last in the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your tables are using an ablsolute position:

```
table {
position:absolute;
}
```

After that set the top, left, right or bottom values to set where you want to place the table.

Comment: "getting that bar that says Top Products" is the problem I think, not the positioning of the table but the bar inside it.

Comment: Could you provide the code you are got at the moment? HTML & CSS

Comment: I am out just now, but I will have a look soon!